# How to save multiple file save in one file

Tags: c#

My friends send me a file. He save multiple gif file in one file and he give me list like

```
file1 - StartFrom - 1 and length 18493,
file2 - StartFrom - 132089 and length 824,
file3 - StartFrom - 18494 and length 2476 etc..
```

I don't know how he put all gif file into one file. I need extract all gif image from this file.

Is anyone help me one how i write a code in vb.net or C# . I write a code below:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    byte[] buffer = new byte[18493];


    string destPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\mm.gif";
    string sourcePath = Application.StartupPath + "\\Data.qdd";

    var destStream = new FileStream(destPath, FileMode.Create);

    int read;
    var sourceStream = new FileStream(sourcePath, FileMode.Open);
    while ((read = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 1, 18493)) != 0)
          destStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);

}
```

But there is and error show is :

> Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.

Comment: Whap your friend over the head and tell him to send you a ZIP archive like a normal person?

Comment: @ipavlic The `homework` tag died in a fire, try and judge the question on its own merit instead of guessing at the context.

Comment: Anyway. What line does the error occur at? What are the values of the parameters you're passing to the method being called at that line? Basically, fire up a debugger and first try to gather whatever information you can in it.

Comment: This happens most probably because the file isn't *exactly* sized as a a multiple of the size of the buffer.

Comment: Anyway, my guess is that the call should be `sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, 18943)` - you're not pointing at the start of the buffer, but the second item.

Comment: That said, your code isn't correct anyway. What you have won't read the first `N` bytes of the file then move on to something else. It will just read the whole file, doing so in chunks of `N` bytes or less. To read exactly the first `N` bytes, you'll have to keep track of the total number of bytes read so far, and in your read call do something like `source.Read(buffer, 0, N-totalRead);`, stopping when `totalRead == N`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT edited solution**

The error lies here

```
read = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 1, 18493)
```

You create a *buffer* byte array variable with length 18493, so it has 18493 elements.
The position in the array are from 0 to 18492.
The ***Read*** function try to write 18943 byte from position 1, so the last byte will be written to buffer[18943] going out of the limit of your array.
Try to change the read to

```
read = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, 18493)
```

**EDIT 2 Solution to the whole problem**

To solve the problem and not just the error you should allocate three different buffer and write free different file. (You could use just one buffer and clean it every time, but is easier to understand if you use three of them)
You cannot use a while to read because in that way you'll go to the end of the file!
Just read the file for the desired lenght and then move for the next file.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    byte[] buffer1 = new byte[18493];
    byte[] buffer2 = new byte[824];
    byte[] buffer3 = new byte[2476];


    string destPath1 = Application.StartupPath + "\\mm1.gif";
    string destPath2 = Application.StartupPath + "\\mm2.gif";
    string destPath3 = Application.StartupPath + "\\mm3.gif";
    string sourcePath = Application.StartupPath + "\\Data.qdd";

    var destStream1 = new FileStream(destPath1, FileMode.Create);
    var destStream2 = new FileStream(destPath2, FileMode.Create);
    var destStream3 = new FileStream(destPath3, FileMode.Create);

    int read;
    var sourceStream = new FileStream(sourcePath, FileMode.Open);
    if ((read = sourceStream.Read(buffer1, 0, 18493)) != 0)
          destStream1.Write(buffer1, 0, read);
    //file three is the next in the stream
    if ((read = sourceStream.Read(buffer3, 0, 2476)) != 0)
          destStream3.Write(buffer3, 0, read);
    //there some unused space, move to the start of the second gif file
    sourceStream.Seek(132089, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    if ((read = sourceStream.Read(buffer2, 0, 824)) != 0)
          destStream2.Write(buffer2, 0, read);

}
```

Comment: Thanks to help me. I need little help. My software is working good. but problem in that image is not show. I think Main sourch file (Data.qdd) is not image format. I extract from main file but i think i need to save file in gif image format. How do i convert gif image format.

Comment: @dralialadin Don't badger with further questions in comments on answers. Post a new question, with sample code and everything. That said, if you don't know what format the original file in, there's no way to magically convert it to .gif

Comment: @dralialadin yes, millimoose is correct. You should open a new question. Also i have no idea on how to convert it to .gif, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
//struct to store information about file
struct GifFile
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public int startPosition { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //first we need to get information about files from string.
    String description = @"file1 - StartFrom - 1 and length 18493,
        file2 - StartFrom - 132089 and length 824,
        file3 - StartFrom - 18494 and length 2476";
    String pattern = @"(\w+) - StartFrom - (\d+) and length (\d+)";
    var matches = Regex.Matches(description, pattern);
    List<GifFile> files = new List<GifFile>();
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        GifFile gifFile = new GifFile
        {
            FileName = match.Groups[1].Value,
            startPosition = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value),
            Length = int.Parse(match.Groups[3].Value)
        };
        files.Add(gifFile);
    }

    string sourcePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Data.qdd");
    using (var sourceStream = new FileStream(sourcePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        // for each file in file list we take data and create gif file.
        foreach (GifFile file in files)
        {
            String outputPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, file.FileName + ".gif")
            using (FileStream destStream = new FileStream(outputPath , FileMode.Create))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[file.Length];

                sourceStream.Position = file.startPosition;
                int readLength = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, file.Length);
                if(readLength == file.Length)
                {
                    destStream.Write(buffer, 0, file.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this code could be that stream starts its numeration from 0. So you may set `sourceStream.Position` to `file.startPosition - 1`

Comment: This will break if `Read()` returns less than `file.Length` bytes. (It might not be likely for files this small but it's still ignoring the contract of `Stream.Read()`.)

Comment: and it will also falls if input file not exist. On one side we should use right error handling in examples. On the other side it will make the examples bigger and more difficult to read. Actually, i don't know what is better, but i know what is simplier :)

Comment: This isn't error handling. This is not using `Read()` as it's supposed to be used. `Read()` returning less than the maximum number of bytes is **not an error**, it's an expected occurence that should be handled in any correct code. If that situation happens (very likely if reading from the network for instance), your code will fail silently and do the wrong thing. That's not "omitted error handling", that's a bug, plain and simple.